# Visual Studio - Publish Automation

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, clickonce

I maintain a Winform app deployed to the desktop via ClickOnce.  Currently I use Visual Studio Publish wizard to make a new version available.  I would like to automate this step, ideally via an MSBuild script.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke msbuild /target:publish at the command line, it tells the MSBuild system to build the project and create a ClickOnce application in the publish folder. This is equivalent to selecting the Publish command in the IDE.

This comes from the MSDN documentation for MSBuild

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx